# Нужно сделать выборочное нажатие клавиш

Tags: python, python-keyboard

Всем привет. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии клавиши Y происходило одно, а при нажатии на N - другое. Код:

```
print('Чтобы сыграть ещё раз нажмите Y. Для отказа нажмите N')

while True:
    keyboard.wait('y')
    repeat_play()
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете воспользоваться функцией [keyboard.read_key](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.read_event). И проверить является ли нажатая кнопка нужной.
Пример как это может быть реализовано:

```py
import keyboard

def repeat_play():
   ...

print('Чтобы сыграть ещё раз нажмите Y. Для отказа нажмите N')

while True:
    key = keyboard.read_key() # считываем все нажатия кнопок из консоли
    if key.lower() == 'y':    # если это нужная нам кнопка делаем что надо
        repeat_play()
    elif key.lower() == 'n':  # делаем ещё что то. Например выходим из цикла
        break
    else:             # если кнопка нам не подошла ждём следующего нажатия в цикле
        print("Вы нажали не y или n, попробуйте ещё раз")
```

*lower()* используется чтобы shift + N/Y тоже подходили, но если это не нужно можно не использовать.